# No .BSS in PE file

Tags: windows, assembly, disassembly, portable-executable

Here is short console application example

```
static char buffer[4096];
int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<4096;i++) {
        buffer[i] = 1234;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand, 'exe' file produced by the compiler should contain .bss section to store 'buffer' variable.

I'm using Tiny C Compiler and resulting file does not contain any reference to .bss.

```
DOS Header
Magic number:                    0x5a4d (MZ)
Bytes in last page:              144
Pages in file:                   3
Relocations:                     0
Size of header in paragraphs:    4
Minimum extra paragraphs:        0
Maximum extra paragraphs:        65535
Initial (relative) SS value:     0
Initial SP value:                0xb8
Initial IP value:                0
Initial (relative) CS value:     0
Address of relocation table:     0x40
Overlay number:                  0
OEM identifier:                  0
OEM information:                 0
PE header offset:                0x80

COFF/File header
Machine:                         0x14c IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386
Number of sections:              2
Date/time stamp:                 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC)
Symbol Table offset:             0
Number of symbols:               0
Size of optional header:         0xe0
Characteristics:                 0x30f
                                 IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED
                                 IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE
                                 IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED
                                 IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED
                                 IMAGE_FILE_32BIT_MACHINE
                                 IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED

Optional/Image header
Magic number:                    0x10b (PE32)
Linker major version:            6
Linker minor version:            0
Size of .text section:           0
Size of .data section:           0
Size of .bss section:            0
Entrypoint:                      0x1060
Address of .text section:        0x1000
Address of .data section:        0x2000
ImageBase:                       0x400000
Alignment of sections:           0x1000
Alignment factor:                0x200
Major version of required OS:    4
Minor version of required OS:    0
Major version of image:          0
Minor version of image:          0
Major version of subsystem:      4
Minor version of subsystem:      0
Size of image:                   0x4000
Size of headers:                 0x200
Checksum:                        0x95d5
Subsystem required:              0x3 (IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI)
DLL characteristics:             0
Size of stack to reserve:        0x100000
Size of stack to commit:         0x1000
Size of heap space to reserve:   0x100000
Size of heap space to commit:    0x1000

Data directories
IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:    0x2000 (40 bytes)
IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT:       0x2028 (32 bytes)

Imported functions

msvcrt.dll
                                 _controlfp
                                 __set_app_type
                                 __getmainargs
                                 exit
                                 _XcptFilter
                                 _exit
                                 _except_handler3
export directory not found

Sections
Name:                            .text
Virtual Address:                 0x1000
Physical Address:                0x1e8
Size:                            0x200 (512 bytes)
Pointer To Data:                 0x200
Relocations:                     0
Characteristics:                 0x60000020
                                 IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE
                                 IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE
                                 IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ
Name:                            .data
Virtual Address:                 0x2000
Physical Address:                0x10e0
Size:                            0x200 (512 bytes)
Pointer To Data:                 0x400
Relocations:                     0
Characteristics:                 0xc0000040
                                 IMAGE_SCN_CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
                                 IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ
                                 IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE
```

Disassembled version of executable references 'buffer' variable as if it was positioned right after .data section. How it works ? How PE loader knows that it should reserve particular area after .data section ?

Executable: https://www.dropbox.com/s/99bpil11j7396ej/test-bss.exe?dl=0

PEDUMP online: http://pedump.me/40c40172cf08c89c3d97bd6840dbd3a0/

Comment: It wouldn't take up space, but the PE headers would need to at least indicate the required size for the loader. My guess is that the TCC linker is very bare-bones and doesn't bother with a BSS section but just puts the globals after the .data section by setting the image size appropriately. See if the MS compiler produces a .bss section.

Comment: user3144770 I know, but it should be somehow described in PE.

Comment: Andrew Medico How Image Size should be interpreted in that case ? What size reserved for .bss in example above ? Image Size is 0x4000, .data size is  0x200, .text size is 0x200

Comment: There is no .bss in your example above, as Andrew Medico explained your compiler isn't using that section. Your dump of the executable is incomplete and doesn't include the full section info, which has separate virtual and physical sizes.

Comment: About Andrew Medico's comment: I know that the Watcom linker converts .bss sections to .data sections that are filled with NUL bytes. Maybe the TCC linker also does this. However the size of the .data segment in the example here is too small so this cannot be the reason.

Comment: @RossRidge: There is no separate "virtual size" field in PE files; "physical size" field contains the virtual size if the section is an uninitialized (BSS) section. The virtual size of the .data section should be 0x10e0 in this case.

Comment: @Martin No, if you read the PECOFF specification sections have both a VirtualSize and a SizeOfRawData field, the later being the physical size of the section on disk. If SizeOfRawData is less than VirtualSize then the remainder of the section in memory is filled will zeroes. This is probably what's happened here, the compiler has put `buffer` in the data section somewhere in between the physical end of the data section on disk, but before the virtual end of the data section in memory. But without a complete dump of the section headers, I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @RossRidge: What I wanted to say is that "virtual size" and "physical address" are shared in a C "union". In COFF files for micrcontrollers this 32-bit word has the meaning "virtual size" for BSS sections and "physical address" for other sections. For Windows EXE files the field has always the meaning "virtual size" (the MSDN web site says so). So the value named "physical address" in the dump is actually the "virtual size".

Comment: @RossRidge I have added links to executable and results of online pedump analysis. Size of raw data is 512, virtual size is 4320. 4320-512=3808 which is lesser than 4096 required for buffer. What am I missing ?

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov: The "size" value of the section seems to be required to be rounded up to the file alignment. I wrote a linker myself some time ago and found out that Windows will not accept sections whose "size" is not a multiple of the file alignment. So I think that the actual .data section is only 4320-4096=224 bytes long and the remaining 512-224=288 bytes of the .data section are actually the first 288 bytes of the .bss section. You may check this by modifying the PE file with a HEX editor...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the actual in memory and on disk size of the .data section now known I think it's possible to explain where `buffer` is located and how it got there.

For the sake of consistency I'm using terms from the [Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx).

So this is what we know about the .data section, it's VirtualSize is 4320 (0x10E0) and it's SizeOfRawData is 512 (0x200). This means that the .data section 512 bytes on disk, but gets zero padded to a size of 4320 bytes in memory. The SizeOfRawData value is the size of initialized data in the executable, and when you subtract that from VirtualSize and you get the size of uninitialized data. As noted in the comments, this means the .data section has 3808 bytes of uninitialized data, which isn't enough space to contain the 4096 byte array named `buffer`.

So where is `buffer`? It must start somewhere in the initialized part of the .data section and continue into the uninitialized part. PECOFF requires that SizeOfRawData value be rounded up to the next multiple of FileAlignment (512). This means that when the linker created the executable's .data section it padded out the initialized data on disk with uninitialized data so that SizeOfRawData ends up being a multiple of 512. In other words the actual amount of initialized data in the executable is less than 512 bytes and the actual amount of uninitialized data is greater than 3808.

This diagram attempts to show how the linker would have laid out the .data section. The top part represents where in memory, relative to the start of the .data section, the linker put all the initialized variables and uninitialized variables used in the executable. The middle part shows where `buffer` was placed. The bottom section shows the part of the .data section that exists as initialized data in the executable.

```
+------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Initialized Vars | Uninitialized Variables                |
+--------------------+-----------------------------------+--+
|                    | buffer[4096]                      |  |
+--------------------+---+-------------------------------+--+
| Initialized on Disk    |                                  4320
+------------------------+
0                        512
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to store a BSS section in the exe file because it contains only uninitialised data. It is allocated by the startup code -- that is the code executed before you get to main. The BSS section is normally allocated after the DATA section from RAM, and is NORMALLY (not always) cleared to zero by the startup code.
Conversely DATA section IS initialised (with the values to specify in the source) so it must be store in the exe file image.

Comment: The contents of the BSS aren't stored in the exe, but the PE headers have to list a size for it if there is one.  This question is about the exe not having a BSS at all, not that the literal zeros aren't there.